# "multiple overloads" using templated class with duplicate types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading

I'm trying to write a class that takes two templated types. This class inherits from an interface. See the below code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class IObserver {
 public:
  virtual void Next(const T& value) noexcept = 0;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class BinaryObserver : public IObserver<T1>, public IObserver<T2> {
 public:
  void Next(const T1& value) noexcept override{};

  void Next(const T2& value) noexcept override{};
};

int main() {
  // This is OK
  BinaryObserver<int, float> mc1;
  mc1.Next(0);
  mc1.Next(0.0f);

  // This fails to compile with "multiple overloads"
  BinaryObserver<int, int> mc2;
  mc2.Next(0);
  mc2.Next(0);
}
```

I'm having trouble when `T1` is the same type as `T2`. Obviously this means two `Next` functions will be generated with the same type, which gives an error: `multiple overloads of 'Next' instantiate to the same signature`.

What's an idiomatic way of fixing this? I'm not sure how to handle the case when T1=T2 since I'd only need one `Next` function generated

Thanks!

Comment: It's not just the multiple overloads (which you can fix with some `enable_if` magic) but you are also deriving twice from the same base class which is also not allowed. @VTT's answer fixes both issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about a specialization:

```
template <typename T>
class BinaryObserver<T, T> : public IObserver<T> {
 public:
  void Next(const T & value) noexcept override{};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have another issue in your program:

```
BinaryObserver<int, int> mc2;
mc2.Next(0);
mc2.Next(0);
```

Which one of the `Next` you expect the compiler would choose in case you succeed?
In the VIT's answer you will have only a sigle `Next` implemented in specification and calling it twice will do something different.

So, the best solution is to have different `IObserver` classes with different function names to overload, i.e

```
class BinaryObserver : public IObserver<T1>, public IObserver1<T2> 
...
mc2.Next(0);
mc2.Next1(0);
```

Another possibility is to put one of  `T`s in another container. I used Shell struct in this example:

template 
    struct Shell {
      T t;
      Shell(T t): t(t){}
      operator T() const {return t;}
    };

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class BinaryObserver : public IObserver<T1>, public IObserver<Shell<T2>> {
 public:
  void Next(const T1& value) noexcept override{T1 t = value;};
  void Next(const Shell<T2>& value) noexcept override{T2 t = value;};
};

...

  BinaryObserver<int, float> mc1;
  mc1.Next(0);
  mc1.Next(0.0f);

  BinaryObserver<int, int> mc2;
  mc2.Next(0);
  mc2.Next(Shell<int>(0));
```